# reactjs sidemenu functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, sidebar

I am have a sidebar that is fixed with icons to navigate to different pages. when the icons are clicked, a secondary menu slides out. Currently when an icon is clicked, the menu slides out, but when another icon is selected, the menu slides back in rather than just switching or staying out. Also clicking out of the sidebar and menu does not close the sliding menu. I am not sure how to get this to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Parent:

```js
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false,
    };
  }

  toggleMenuOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <NavIcons onClick={this.toggleMenuOpen} />
          <PushMenu menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Icons on sidebar:

```js
export default class NavIcons extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          topNavListItems.map((topItem) => {
            return (
              <li className='link-wrapper' key={topItem.get('id')} onClick={onClick}>
                  <NavLink
                    activeClassName='selected'
                    className='Icon-list-link'
                    to={topItem.get('route')}
                    >
                      <Icon name={topItem.get('name')} />
                  </NavLink>
              </li>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NavIcons.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Slide out menu:

```js
export default class PushMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const { menuOpen } = this.props;
    const menuClass = menuOpen ? 'menu open' : 'menu';
    return (
      <div className={menuClass}>
        <Header>Content</Header>
        <Linebreak />
        <List>
          {
            labelMenuItems.map((menuItem) => {
              return (
                <li key={menuItem.get('id')}>{menuItem.get('name')}
                  <List>
                    {
                    menuItem.get('nestedItems').map((childMenuItem) => {
                      return (
                        <li key={childMenuItem.get('id')}>{childMenuItem.get('name')}</li>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </List>
                </li>
              );
            })
          }
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PushMenu.propTypes = {
  menuOpen: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Comment: Please include the other components you are mentioning in your code so we can test and find a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have a single `toggleMenuOpen` handler, create `openMenu` and `closeMenu` handlers

```
openMenu = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (!prevState.menuOpen) {
      return { menuOpen: true };
    }
    return {};
  })
}

closeMenu = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    if (prevState.menuOpen) {
      return { menuOpen: false };
    }
    return {};
  })
}
```

You can then use `openMenu` as the `onClick` handler for your top-level nav `li` items

If you have access to the main content in the `Parent` component, you can also handle the close-on-click-outside (if not, you would need to hoist the `menuOpen` state up to where you can). Use `closeMenu` as a click handler on the "outside" content - whatever's not in the slideout menu. You would want to make sure to only set that handler when the menu is open. There are many ways to do this but this is one:

```
render() {
  const handleCloseWhenOpen = this.state.menuOpen ? { onClick: this.closeMenu } : {};
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <NavIcons onClick={this.toggleMenuOpen} />
        <PushMenu menuOpen={this.state.menuOpen} />
      </ul>
      <MainContent {...handleCloseWhenOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```